# Enabling a new content type in the add new content

Tags: nodes

i have created a new content type but when i go to add content, it does not appear but only appears under content types. I have even tried to clear the caches but all in vein, what could be the cause? i will glad for your help

Comment: You do it as which user? And what do you see when you go to http://example.com/node/add/content_type_machine_name ?

Comment: Also, what happens if you try that as UID 1 (aka admin, first user)?

Comment: as administrator

Comment: OK, and what about the other details I requested? Come on, it is your problem, so show some effort in solving it!

Answer (score 0):

Go to structure >> Menus >> Navigation (admin/structure/menu/manage/navigation) and make sure to enable the content type link in that list.

Here I'm showing example for Article Content type.

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't it be "on" by default?

Comment: @Mołot As far as I know, If it's a core menu (default content types, Article, Basic Page) Yes, it will be "on" by default. Here I added screenshot for better understand.

Comment: yes i have tried to enable it but still it can't appear i really do not know what has happened.

Comment: @mase see my comment under your question. provide informations I asked about, and we might try to help more.

Comment: @mase you have mentioned "i have created a new content type" how did you create that? I think Molot already asked in comment please respond

Comment: i went to structure-content types-add new content type. it shows it has been created fine but when i click on add content my newly created content type does not appear even after clearing the caches and redoing it time and again.

Comment: @mase Did you find that under navigation menu list? and are you logged in as admin? or does the logged in user has permission to create that note type?

Comment: yes! it appears in the navigation menu list and am logged in as an administrator

Comment: Thanks for the help, despite failure but ive resolved the issue by restoring my database with the one i had backed up last week before the problem happened and now am able to create content. thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this problem, that is a new content type is not showing under `Add content` (or `node/add`) even though it was showing under `Content types` (`admin/structure/types`)

Check your modules and their permissions. I found that `view_unpublished` module has a `View any unpublished content` permission that prevents that content type displaying completely.